# posix timer_create() function causing memory leak on linux

Tags: c++

I am using timer_create function for timer functionality in my application.
When timeout happens, a new thread gets created. That time my application's memory usage is getting increased by around 11mb. I also have set the thread attribute to PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED. Any help is appreciated. I also want to know how long will the thread that gets created when timeout happens be alive?

Comment: code speaks louder than words

Answer (score 1):

[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is an invaluable tool for finding memory leaks in a Linux environment

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it has anything to do with your timer.

If you create a new thread, the thread needs space for the stack. As far as I know this memory gets allocated once at thread creation because it has to be contiguous.

That may sound like a lot of wasted memory, but it is not. First off, you can lower the stack size if you want, second: Only the address-space inside your process gets allocated. Physical memory only gets allocated if you use the stack.

Answer (score 0):

This question makes no sense without the code.

timer_create does not make a thread by itself. Your code must be making the thread.

Your memory leak is almost certainly caused by something wrong in your code. Since we can't see your code we can't help solve the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, POSIX timers *do* create threads at timer expiry time, if you use the `SIGEV_THREAD` event notification mechanism.  It is a slightly insane API.

Answer (score 0):

Any thread stays "active" until you exit its thread function. Your leak is most probably the thread's stack - that will not go away until you invoke thread_join or some such.

Answer (score 0):

Too few info given, but **maybe** helps:
[Periodic Timer Overrun and Resource Allocation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/timer_create.html#tag_03_776_08_01)