# posix timer_create() problem on linux

Tags: linux, posix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [posix timer_create() function causing memory leak on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135415/posix-timer-create-function-causing-memory-leak-on-linux)

I am using posix `timer_create()` function for timer functionality in my application. I am using SIGEV_THREAD option for timeout scenario. But the thread created by kernel at run time when timeout happens in not exiting. There is no problem with the start function of thread also. For testing purpose, I have made it a dummy function. As this thread is not exiting, it is causing a memroy leak of around 10mb. The detach state for the thread created by default is PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED. Can somebody tell me what to do to get rid of the memory leak?

Comment: Please stop making these duplicate posts.

Comment: If you want a better answer than you got last time then post some code.

Answer (score 0):

This is libc library creating a thread to handle timers for you. This thread does not get destroyed after your timer has fired to avoid creating/destroying threads each time you use `timer_create()`. In other words, once a timer thread has been created it runs till the program terminates.

However, the timer thread itself does not cause any memory leaks. The memory leak is most likely caused by your code. Post your code please.